# Python ctypes how to pass string and array arguments

Tags: python, excel, vba, numpy, ctypes

I have a dll with various functions available and an example of it being used in Excel VBA.  I'm attempting to call the DLL from python.

The following is the function's declaration in Excel VBA that I'm trying to use in Python:

```
Declare PtrSafe Function readparameter Lib "DATAREADER" Alias "__readparameter@32" (ByRef hfile As Long, ByVal parmname As String, ByRef tstart As Double, ByRef tstop As Double, ByRef htref As Long, ByRef time As Single, ByRef data As Single, ByRef npoints As Long) As Long
```

The function call in Excel looks like this:

```
hparm = readparameter(hfile, pidname, starttim, stoptime, htref, time(1), data(1), npoints)
```

...where each parameter is the type indicated in the declaration. time and data are 1-D Single arrays.

The documentation has the following info:

> ```
>     readparameter(hfile,parmname,starttime,stoptime,htref,timearry,dataarry,npoints) - Retrieves parameter data from selected file
>         Arguments:
>             integer*4 hfile, input, a valid handle to a file structure (as returned by opendatafile())
>             character*256 parmname, input, string buffer containing the parameter to be retrieved.
>             real*8, starttime, input, starting time of data retreival (relative to htref, if used).
>             real*8, stoptime, input, ending time of data retrieval (relative to htref, if used).
>             integer*4 htref, input, handle to a data structure representing a t-zero reference point (can be 0).
>             real*4 timearry(), output, data array to contain time stamps of retrieved data (size defined by npoints).
>             real*4 dataarry(), output, data array to contain values of retrieved parameter data (size defined by npoints).
>             integer*4 npoints, input+output, on input defines the size of timearry and dataarry, on output defines the number of points returned.
>         Returns:
>             0 on fail, else handle to parameter data structure (to be used by other functions).
> ```

So far I've pieced together the following script:

```
import os
import numpy as np
from numpy.ctypeslib import ndpointer
import ctypes
from ctypes import cdll, CDLL, WinDLL
from ctypes import *

libpath = r'D:\DataReader'
libname = r'DataReader.dll'

os.environ['PATH'] = os.environ['PATH'] + ';' + libpath + '\\'

EasyRead = cdll.LoadLibrary('DATAREADER')

filename = ctypes.create_string_buffer(b'D:\test.dat')

hfile = DataRead.opendatafile(filename)
pidname = ctypes.create_string_buffer(b'sine', 256)
starttime = 0.0
stoptime = 10.0
timedelta = 1
htref = 0
npoints = 1000
time_np = np.zeros(npoints, np.double)
data_np = np.zeros(npoints, np.double)
make_array_pointer = lambda x: (x.ctypes.data + np.arange(x.shape[0]) * x.strides[0]).astype(np.uintp)
time_c = make_array_pointer(time_np)
data_c = make_array_pointer(data_np)
double_type = np.ctypeslib.ndpointer(dtype=np.uintp)

DataReader.readparameter.argtypes = [ctypes.c_long, ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.c_double, ctypes.c_double, ctypes.c_long, double_type, double_type, ctypes.c_long]

hparm = DataReader.readparameter(hfile, pidname, starttime, stoptime, htref, time_c, data_c, npoints)
```

...which results in `OS Error: exception: access violation reading 0x00000000`.

I'm not sure I'm setting up the arguments and their data types correctly.  In the VBA declaration it looks like declarations were simply made in common VBA data types and then those native VBA variables were passed directly.  How do I appropriately tell ctypes which Python/numpy type I'd like to pass in?  Is that even the problem here?  I'm very inexperienced working with C data types and have cobbled together the ctypes stuff from various Google searches, but don't really understand if ctypes.c_char_p is appropriate for passing in a string, or whether I'm doing the arrays correctly.

Any help would be great.  I'm sorry that I'm unable to share the DLL source.

Comment: `ByRef` means an argument has to be passed by reference, i.e. the argument is the address of the value. Define some pointer types: `c_long_p = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_long);` `c_double_p = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double);` `c_float_p = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float)` to use in the prototype `readparameter.argtypes = (c_long_p, ctypes.c_char_p, c_double_p, c_double_p, c_long_p, c_float_p, c_float_p, c_long_p)`. Check the return type of `opendatafile`; it may return a pointer.

Comment: You'll need ctypes objects for the byref parameters, e.g. `starttime = ctypes.c_double(0)`, which gets passed as `ctypes.byref(starttime)`. For the arrays, start with a ctypes float array, e.g. `time_c = (ctypes.c_float * npoints)()`. Get that working before adding support for NumPy arrays.